# How to match text in a non-greedy manner with regex for a specific recurrence

Tags: python, regex

With the regex pattern (Python):

```
(?<=start<).*?(?=>end)
```

I'd like to match/select only the most internal text of the following string:

> start< obj1 obj2 start< obj3 >end

that is:

> obj3

I use Pythex as online regex tester for my code ([link](https://pythex.org/?regex=(%3F%3C%3Dstart%3C).*%3F(%3F%3D%3Eend)&test_string=start%3C%20obj1%20obj2%20start%3C%20obj3%20%3Eend&ignorecase=0&multiline=0&dotall=0&verbose=0))). Pythex returns

> obj1 obj2 start< obj3

instead of

> obj3

Do you know a way to force the match of the most internal text? Maybe with some extra python code (if it is impossible with regex alone)?

Thanks

**UPDATE 01**
Sorry, I've tested your solutions (all) with different kinds of strings but I can't obtain what I want that is: match all between "start<" and ">end" but excluding strings containing "start<" and other characters before "start<".

For example if I have the string

> start< obj1 >end start< obj2 >end start< obj3 start< obj4 >end

where "obj4" is equal to "<" (for example), no method/pattern proposed works because no method can match "<" at the end of the string. For the string above I'd like to obtain the following matched text (findall):

1. **obj1**
2. **obj2**
3. **obj3**
4. **<**

regardless of what "obj4" is (so the method I'm searching should work in general also if obj# is equal to "<").

Can you suggest some other solutions?

Thank you

Comment: could you simply add a space character before to make it `(?<= start<).*?(?=end)`?

Comment: Hi, thank you for reply, good answer for the original string, but doesn't work if we have `start< obj1 obj2 start< start< obj3 >end` (three `start<` instead of two).

Answer (score 0):

Use the following approach with improved regex pattern:

```
import re

s = 'start< obj1 obj2 start< obj3 >end'
m = re.search(r'(?<=start<)[^<]*?(?=>?end)', s)
res = m.group().strip() if m else m
print(res)    # obj3
```

Comment: ***On side note:-*** IMO `[^<]*?` no need of `?` as `[^<]*` this is already lazy by nature

Comment: Hi, it works, thanks. Ok also the @CodeManiac version. I will try to play a little to understand this regex.

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest How can I match also "<" if it is between "start<" and ">end"?

Answer (score 0):

What about this?

```
r'start.*<(.*)>.*end'
```

In this case, the first `*` is so greedy that matches everything up to the last `<`. This gives you the inner text (accessible by `group(1)`).

Comment: Hi, good also this solution for the original string. I played a little and I've see that if we have the string `start< obj1 obj2 start< obj3 >end start< obj4 >end`, this regex matches only `obj4` and not also `obj3`, which is at the same depth level as `obj4`.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done without lookahed or lookbehind, too:

```
s= "start< obj1 obj2 start< obj3 >end"
m=re.search(r"start<\s*([^<]*?)\s*>end",s)
>>> m[1]
>>> 'obj3'
```

Comment: Hi, it works also for string like `start< obj1 >end >end >end obj2 start< start< obj3 >end start< start< obj4 >end`. I try to test this regex with other types of string similar and more complex to the original one. Thank you.

Comment: @MatteoVR You mean using re.findall(), right?

Comment: Hi, yes I use re.findall() in my script.

Comment: How can I match also "<" if it is between "start<" and ">end"?